Unable to start Django app, error related to what seems like a circular import?
I'm currently attempting to build my first django app, a resume website. I get this error when trying to start the app.
<class 'mainapp.admin.CertificateAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[3]' refers to 'is_active', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'CertificateAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'mainapp.Certificate'.

This is what I have in my models.py file related to "certificate" (comments included):
class Certificate(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Certificates'
        verbose_name = 'Certificate'

    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)  # When the certificate was earned
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Name of the certificate
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)  # Title or description of the certificate
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Additional details about the certificate
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

And this is what I have in my admin.py file:
@admin.register(Certificate)
class CertificateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'title', 'is_active')  # Display 'id', 'name', and 'is_active' fields

ChatGPT has been no help so far, only circular answers to make sure 'is_active' is properly called, I'm not sure it is, it seems like it (I'm sort of a beginner).
I'm following instructions from a youtube video (yes, I have been learning python and django since last year, did not follow THAT blindly!), the "is_active" part is supposed to be there, as per chatgpt I tried removing it and that made the app start, but had other errors (the page didn't display, and yes, I have all the css and html files in place).

Is there a column in teh database named is_active, do you see this in the migrations?

Pardon my stupidity, by database do you mean the db.sqlite file?

In the admin.py file, instead of using the decorator @admin.register, try this:
class CertificateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'title', 'is_active')

admin.site.register(Certificate,CertificateAdmin)


Yeah, I'm not sure what I did wrong at this point because that didn't change anything, I get the same exact error still.
